# yield data from a keras data generator

Tags: keras

I'm looking to preview the output of a keras image data generator. How would I yield, for example, 5 images from a generator?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

trying the usual way of going through an iterator doesn't seem to work

```
for image in train_generator:
    print(image)
```

`AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Answer (score 0):

This yields the first three images from the dataset:

```
data, labels = generator_train._get_batches_of_transformed_samples([1, 2, 3])
```